# Swift 5: Wrong change tag when send a function to GestureRecognizer

Tags: swift, function, callback, uigesturerecognizer

I want to send a function like a parameter into gesturerecognizer, and add to UIlabel. 
So I make a function like that:

```html
final class ActionTag: NSObject {
    var tag = 0
    private let _action: (Int) -> ()

    init(action: @escaping (Int) -> ()) {
        _action = action
        super.init()
    }

    @objc func action() {
        _action(tag)
    }
}
```

In my function, I have a bit of code:

```html
for index in 0..<5 {
      let dateLabel = UILabel()
      dateLabel.tag = index + 1
      addDoublePress(label: dateLabel, doubleTap: planDateDidDoubleTapped)

}
```

with define here:

```html
private func addDoublePress(label: UILabel, doubleTap: ActionTag) {
        label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        doubleTap.tag = label.tag

        let doubleTapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: doubleTap, action: #selector(doubleTap.action))
        doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
        label.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapRecognizer)
    }

    private let planDateDidDoubleTapped = ActionTag { tag in
        print("planDateDidDoubleTapped need implemention = \(tag)")
    }
```

but when running, I got that as:
planDateDidDoubleTapped need implemention = 5
Why the tag kept only one value(5)?

Comment: I know why I get this error. Because the planDateDidDoubleTapped kept one reference, so When I change tag from 1 to 5, the tag will kep last value.

Comment: Now I want to kept different value for each label. how the way make that?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolve that problem.
I change class ActionTag like that:

```html
final class ActionTag: NSObject {
        private let _action: (UITapGestureRecognizer) -> ()

        init(action: @escaping (UITapGestureRecognizer) -> ()) {
            _action = action
            super.init()
        }

        @objc func action(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
            _action(sender)
        }
    }
```

I get tag like that:

```html
private let planDateDidDoubleTapped = ActionTag { sender in
        guard let tag = (sender.view as? UILabel)?.tag else { return }
        print("planDateDidDoubleTapped need implemention = \(tag)")

    }
```

I post my answer for everyone take care it. thanks